# Python excel count number of values of one column based on combination of other columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have this excel sheet which has below sample data(text format data in Edit section at the bottom):

[image]

What I want to do is:

1. For each (language,vendor,filename), calculate the total count of score values(not the sum of scores but total number of scores). So something similar to this(text format data in Edit section at the bottom):

[image]

2. For each (language,vendor,filename), calculate the total count of score values(not the sum of scores but total number of scores) where score value is higher than 0.6

In my python code, I am able to read the excel file into a pandas dataframe using:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile


def read_scores_excel():

    df = pd.read_excel('scores.xlsx', sheet_name='scores')

    print("Column headings:")
    print(df.columns)

    languages = df['language']
    vendor_name = df['vendor']
    file_anme = df['filename']
    score = df['score']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_scores_excel()
```

But I am unable to proceed further to get the logic implemented. How can I get the logic implemented so that I can get the count values?

**Edit:**

**Sample input data in text:**

```
vendor  filename    language    score
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.67717278
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.644506991
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.999999523
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.756420255
Vendor 1    File 1  chinese 0.737005472
Vendor 2    File 2  Japanese    0.637181938
Vendor 2    File 2  Japanese    0.756420255
Vendor 2    File 2  Japanese    0.737005472
Vendor 2    File 2  Japanese    0.637181938
Vendor 2    File 1  chinese 0.637181938
Vendor 3    File 1  chinese 0.637181938
Vendor 3    File 1  chinese 0.737005472
Vendor 3    File 3  English 0.637181938
Vendor 3    File 3  English 0.756420255
Vendor 3    File 3  English 0.737005472
Vendor 3    File 3  English 0.637181938
```

**Sample output data in text:**

```
Chinese Vendor 1    File 1  190
Chinese Vendor 1    File 2  187
Chinese Vendor 2    File 1  245
Chinese Vendor 2    File 2  225
Japnese Vendor 1    File 1  245
Japnese Vendor 1    File 3  212
English Vendor 1    File 1  245
English Vendor 3    File 3  245
```

Comment: Please make sure to include your sample/expected data as text.

Comment: Looks like `df.groupby['langue','vendor','filename'].size()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have added sample input data and output expected data in text format in above post

Comment: @QuangHoang when I do `df.groupby['language','vendor','filename'].size()`,  I get following error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I forgot a `()` pair around `[...]`: `df.groupby(['language',...']).size()`.

Comment: similarly just `df[df["score"]>0.6].groupby(["language",..."]).size()` for 2nd part

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick:

```
df.groupby(['language', 'vendor','filename']) \
  .agg(score_count=('score', 'count'))
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd


test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ('Vendor 1', 'File 1', 'chinese', 0.67717278),
        ('Vendor 1', 'File 1', 'chinese', 0.737005472),
        ('Vendor 2', 'File 2', 'Japanese',0.637181938),
    ], 
    columns=['vendor', 'filename', 'language', 'score']
)


print(test_df.groupby(['language', 'vendor','filename']).agg(score_count=('score', 'count')))
```

and the output would be:

```
                            score_count
language vendor   filename             
Japanese Vendor 2 File 2              1
chinese  Vendor 1 File 1              2
```